# How to add a new column to a grid?

Tags: datagrid

I have a `datagrid` with two columns and with two buttons inside the grid: *edit* and *delete*.

When I click on *edit* I want a new column to be added to the grid.

How do I this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the method `datagrid.Columns.Add()`.

Answer (score 0):

As Sjoerd said, use the method but it will not have a name. You would need to add the name of the column in the method unless you edit it directly in the datagrid.